# Using ASP.NET Identity with LDAP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I use **ASP.NET Identity** version 2 in my **MVC5** application and manipulate Role Management without any problem. On the other hand, I want to let our **LDAP** users to be able to login to the application by using their **LDAP** credentials. However, I am not sure if the following approach is good in order to use **ASP.NET Identity** and **LDAP** properly. The scenario is something like that:

**1)** The user login to the system using his/her LDAP credentials.

**2)** The user is checked if there is such a user in LDAP:

**2.a)** If the user is authenticated, all the roles will be assigned to the user by retrieving roles from ASP.NET Identity role table (AspNetRoles).

**2.b)** If the user is authenticated, but there is no role assigned to this user then a default role will be added to the ASP.NET Identity role table (AspNetRoles) and this default role will be assigned to the user as shown below:

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string[] roles = GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
        var id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            id.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach to perform this? Should I put this method to the **AccountController**? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/ Though I don't do roles manipulation and effectively throw away Identity. But can give you code samples for authentication against LDAP

Comment: @trailmax Many thanks for your reply. It was useful but I am not sure if it meets my requirements. Nevertheless, I will have a look at and give a try. On the other hand, I need to create a new user if the user does not exist on ASP.NET Identity User table. How to manage it? Any idea?

Comment: No, it is not direct answer to your question - hence only a comment. You'll need to implement `PasswordValidator` that dips into LDAP, but also make sure user record exists in Identity tables. Quite a complex solution - unlikely you'll find a good off-the shelf answer to all your questions.